# Extra set of eyes needed with onItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

I have done everything that I could possibly do to figure out what is wrong with my onItemClickListener.  There was one helpful person who tried to help but he or she said that they absolutely don't see anything wrong and that they do not understand why it is not working. I have done a lot reseach and looking other people codes trying to relate the issues but it still doesn't work. I really need a lot of set of eyes to assist me through this problem.

List Activity:

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
     final String TAG_QUERY = "query";

            JSONArray question = null;          
            android.widget.ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

    questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 


    new LoadAllData().execute();

        }


    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        private Dialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog; 
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {
                    //question = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTION);


                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String NumAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);

                               questionList.add(map);


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION    ; 



        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listview,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter); 
        }

    }

@Override   
protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

     String Subject = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Subject)).getText().toString();
     String Content = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Content)).getText().toString();
     String ChosenAnswer = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ChosenAnswer)).getText().toString();


     Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
     i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT", Subject);
     i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT", Content);
     i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER", ChosenAnswer);
     startActivity(i);

        }

}
```

Issue is that my onItemClickListener is not being called similar to every other problem.

listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Subject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NumAnswers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ChosenAnswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  >
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListActivity` class comes with a protected method [`onListItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29), override that with your handler code and do not call `setOnItemClickListener` directly. The `ListActivity` takes care of all initialization.

---

When using your layout: Your `ListView` has a wrong id. In XML, use the id

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

From the [ListActivity reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> [...] setting your own view layout with `setContentView()` in
>   `onCreate()`. To do this, your own view MUST contain a `ListView` object
>   with the id `"@android:id/list"` (or `android.R.id.list` if it's in code)

Comment: When ever I try to override onListItemClick I get an syntax error underneath `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {` that says this method must have override or implement a supertype method even when I put this underneath `onListItemClick` `super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);` Any ideas why?

Comment: Post the whole class overriding `onListItemClick`, maybe I can spot it in there.

Comment: Your signature must be `protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`, as your class is called `ListView`. You might consider another name, too.

Comment: `OnListitemClick` still doesn't seem to be getting called. Do you think it could be something in my listview.xml and I shall also post updated code.

Comment: Did you see my updated question? I have done some extra research and if you can not find anything that is wrong with the `onItemClickListener` I think it might have something to do with my apk not being updated

Comment: The code you posted worked for me (stripped down the JSON stuff and did some static adding, and simple layout for list elements). I think the issue is your layout. I thought the layout was intended for the whole activity and now dropped, but you load the layout into each row. I doubt you want a `ListView` full of `ListView`s and `ScrollView`s? Remove them or use something like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` (`TextView`s: `android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2`).

Comment: Everything works fine now I just had to delete scroll view because I believe `ListActivity` already has one so I appreciate your help you made me open my mind and think to the root of this problem! Many Thanks!